# Troubles installing ROS Kinetic on Linux Mint Sarah 18

Tags: linux, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to install ROS Kinetic on my Linux Mint 18 running laptop. As far as I am aware of, Sarah 18 is based on Linux kernel 4.4 and an Ubuntu 16.04 package base. Following the wiki installation manual, I am running into the following errors (when calling `apt-get update`):

```
Err:11 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Ign:12 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic/main Translation-en
Fetched 190 kB in 5s (33,2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is this problem related to the fact that I am not using Ubuntu? Are there any methods of installing ROS on Linux Mint Sarah 18?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245325/troubles-installing-ros-kinetic-on-linux-mint-sarah-18/) by [Florian_W](https://answers.ros.org/users/24926/florian_w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this link - http://insane-on-linux.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/installing-ros-indigo-on-mint-17.html

It's a problem with the auto-genned source

---

Originally posted by [jac83](https://answers.ros.org/users/28307/jac83/) with karma: 56 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Treize](https://answers.ros.org/users/27372/treize/) on 2018-02-20**:
This comment helped me resolve the same error I experienced when calling '`apt-get update`' on the Raspberry Pi 3. Thank You